# What is the difference between duration and delay on Ranorex?

Tags: automation, ranorex

I would like to learn difference between **Duration** and **Delay** terms on Ranorex tool. Here is an image from my exercise :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ranorex the term "Delay" refers to an action that the system will take, i.e. it will DELAY execution of the test for an amount of time (the Duration to be exact).

A "Duration" on a test step is the time to wait BEFORE THE NEXT STEP IS EXECUTED.  This is important because it is backwards from what many might understand.  Duration does not delay the step it is on, but instead delays the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this app, but duration is a measure of "**ending time minus starting time**" of something, and delay is the time before "**starting time**". I hope it helps.

Comment: For this tool, your answer is not enough. I don't understand differencies them on Ranorex. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Delay**

A Delay is just a *normal* action in Ranorex. Other Actions are Mouse, Key Sequence, Validation, ...

It does what the name says. Once this action is executed, it simply delays the execution of the next action for an exact amount of time.

**Duration**

A Duration is a certain property that all Actions have. Other properties of Actions are Continue on fail, Enabled, ...

The tooltip of the Duration property in Ranorex Studio 10.1.2 says: "The amount of time the entire action takes to execute, including wait time before the next action starts. Does not influence how fast the action itself is performed in the AUT. Example: For a Mouse click action with 10s duration, the click performs in a few ms, but Ranorex Studio then waits the full 10s before it executes the next action, effectively adding a delay. 0ms performs the action and then immediately starts the next action (may cause issues if the AUT isn't highly responsive). Duration does NOT include effective timeout value of a repository item linked to the action.